# C# Data Model that will allow deserialization of array with no names

Tags: c#, json.net, datamodel

I'm trying to deserialize a response from an API.

```
[
  {
    "field1": "value a",
    "field2": "value b"
  },
  {
    "field1": "value c",
    "field2": "value d`"
  }
]
```

And I'm getting an error...

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'myProject.Models.MyDataModelRoot' because the type requires a JSON object to deserialize correctly.  To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object or change the deserialzed type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface.

I need to make a data model that is representative of the data I'm getting back.

I've tried a couple samples of data models.  Most of them need names and I dont have names...  I tried a suggestion I read on here for a similar problem, but it did not work for me.

```
public class MyDataModelRoot : List<DataEntry>
{

}

public class DataEntry
{

  [JsonProperty(ProperyName = "field1"]
  public string Field1 { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(ProperyName = "field2"]
  public string Field2 { get; set; }

}
```

```
HttpClient httpClient = specialHttpClient.GetHttpClient();
HttpClient.AddCredentials(creds)
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiuri)
MyDataModelRoot dataRoot = await.HttpClient.GetAsync<MyDataModelRoot>(request)  
^^^ This is where it errors...
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `MyDataModelRoot` class does not seem to serve any purpose, as you got a json array to deserialize and you can deserialize it directly into a `List<DataEntry>` list or `DataEntry[]` array.

E.g.:

```
List<DataEntry> dataEntries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataEntry>>(jsonFromResponse);
```

That said, if you insist on using the MyDataModelRoot class for whatever reason, you have to post a [minimal and complete reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question that reproduces the issue. Because the vanilla Newtonsoft.Json library does not seem to have an issue with the `MyDataModelRoot` class as presented in the question when using default
(de)serialization settings (proof: https://dotnetfiddle.net/67kT8o).

Comment: Thanks for getting back!  I tried yout suggestion.  I have to use a special httpclient that does deserialization internally.  It looks like there is no way to make a data model that will work....  maybe I have to not use the special http client and remake this with the regular one...   I added the code above.